# How to log return of multiple functions in order?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of independent functions. Some take longer than others to return.

```
var functionArray = [
    function() {function1()},
    function() {function2()},
    ...
];
```

I'm calling them from a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < functionArray.length; i++) {
    functionArray[i]();
}
```

I have a text field in my app that I'm using as a console and I would like to log the results of function 1 first, 2 second, etc.

Is there a way to do this without callbacks? The callbacks would make each function dependent on the previous one's success.

I suppose I could just run function2() in both a successCallback and an errorCallback of function1() but is there a better way?

Comment: why is the log dependent on each other success if the functions are independent from each other?

Answer (score 0):

If these functions are asynchronous (which I assume from the description), then working with promises and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would make the most sense:

```
Promise.all(functionArray).then(function (results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log(results[i]);
    }
});
```

Note that you'll need to adapt your functions to work with promises then; either you wrap them each in a `Promise` and have them call the `resolve` callback appropriately, or the functions themselves need to return a `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

Closure function may be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < functionArray.length; i++) {
    (function(x) {
        functionArray[i]();
        console.log(x);
    })(i);
}
```